# Howto move an existing Solaris11 installation to a new disk

Tags: solaris, zfs

I want to move an existing Solaris 11 (x86) installation from hdd to a new ssd. Because the ssd is smaller then the hdd, a simple copy with dd is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I managed to find the solution for my problem:**

- boot from dvd/iso
- start console

**create disk label and partition layout**
﻿

```
root@solaris:~# format c2t1d0

selecting c2t1d0 <VMware,-VMware Virtual S-1.0-16.00GB>
[disk formatted]

FORMAT MENU:
        disk       - select a disk
        type       - select (define) a disk type
        partition  - select (define) a partition table
        current    - describe the current disk
        format     - format and analyze the disk
        fdisk      - run the fdisk program
        repair     - repair a defective sector
        label      - write label to the disk
        analyze    - surface analysis
        defect     - defect list management
        backup     - search for backup labels
        verify     - read and display labels
        inquiry    - show disk ID
        volname    - set 8-character volume name
        !<cmd>     - execute <cmd>, then return
        quit
format> part

PARTITION MENU:
        0      - change `0' partition
        1      - change `1' partition
        2      - change `2' partition
        3      - change `3' partition
        4      - change `4' partition
        5      - change `5' partition
        6      - change `6' partition
        select - select a predefined table
        modify - modify a predefined partition table
        name   - name the current table
        print  - display the current table
        label  - write partition map and label to the disk
        !<cmd> - execute <cmd>, then return
        quit
partition> print
Current partition table (original):
Total disk sectors available: 33537981 + 16384 (reserved sectors)

Part      Tag    Flag     First Sector        Size        Last Sector
  0  BIOS_boot    wm                40     260.00MB         532519
  1        usr    wm            532520      15.74GB         33538013
  2 unassigned    wm                 0          0              0
  3 unassigned    wm                 0          0              0
  4 unassigned    wm                 0          0              0
  5 unassigned    wm                 0          0              0
  6 unassigned    wm                 0          0              0
  8   reserved    wm          33538015       8.00MB         33554398

partition> quit


FORMAT MENU:
        disk       - select a disk
        type       - select (define) a disk type
        partition  - select (define) a partition table
        current    - describe the current disk
        format     - format and analyze the disk
        fdisk      - run the fdisk program
        repair     - repair a defective sector
        label      - write label to the disk
        analyze    - surface analysis
        defect     - defect list management
        backup     - search for backup labels
        verify     - read and display labels
        inquiry    - show disk ID
        volname    - set 8-character volume name
        !<cmd>     - execute <cmd>, then return
        quit
format> quit
```

**create new zpool on slice 1 of new disk**

```
root@solaris:~# zpool create rpool1 c2t1d0s1
```

**create recursive snapshot of original zp﻿ool**

```
root@solaris:~# zfs snapshot -r rpool@now
```

﻿**copy snapshot via zfs send|receive to new zpool**

```
root@solaris:~# zfs send -R rpool@now | zfs recv -Fdu rpool1
```

**export both zpools**﻿

```
root@solaris:~# zpool export rpool
root@solaris:~# zpool export rpool1
```

**import new zpool un﻿der the name of the original zpool**

```
root@solaris:~# zpool import -f rpool1 rpool
```

**activate boot environment**﻿

```
root@solaris:~# beadm activate be://rpool/solaris
```

**install bootloader ﻿on new disk**

```
root@solaris:~# bootadm install-bootloader -P rpool
```

**activate boot environment﻿ (without the second activation an error occured)**

```
root@solaris:~# beadm activate be://rpool/solaris
```

**list snapshots**﻿

```
root@solaris:~# zfs list -t snapshots
```

**remove snapshots**

```
root@solaris:~ # zfs destroy -R rpool@now
```

**reboot**

```
root@solaris:# reboot
```

**remove old disk from system**

Comment: Ingenious.  Why not just use `beadm ...` to create a new boot environment on the new disk, though?

Comment: @andrew-henle Oracle removed the -P option from beadm (see https://community.unix.com/t/solaris-11-4-beadm-p/379243)

Comment: Ouch.  That makes maintaining clean, standalone BEs much, much harder.  I can't imagine how convoluted the BE snapshot/clone/swampy mess is going to get after a few years of patches and updates.  I always created new BEs on a pool different from the one I was creating it from just to avoid the cruft buildup.